# Parse XML where an element prefix is defined in the same element

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, xml-namespaces

I have an XML file with an element which looks like this:

```
<wrapping_element>
    <prefix:tag xmlns:prefix="url">value</prefix:tag>
</wrapping_element>
```

I want to get this element, so I am using `lxml` as follows:

```
wrapping_element.find('prefix:tag', wrapping_element.nsmap)
```

but I get the following error: `SyntaxError: prefix 'prefix' not found in prefix map` because `prefix` is not defined before reaching this element in the XML.

Is there a way to get the element anyway?

Comment: I think the problem is rather that wrapping_element.nsmap is empty. I don't even find `find` in the documentation labyrinth, but there seems to be a method `xpath` too, maybe you can use it.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson The thing is, `xpath` requires a `namespaces` argument as `find` does. My problem is that I can't find a way to retrieve the namespace without the element nor the element without the namespace.

Comment: How about `wrapping_element.xpath('/*/*[local-name()="tag"]')`?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Great! I used a relative path: `wrapping_element.xpath('./*[local-name()="tag"]')`, it's working perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned in the comments, you *could* use `local-name()` to circumvent the namespace, but it's easy enough to just handle the namespace directly in the `xpath()` call...

```python
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

wrapping_element = tree.xpath("/wrapping_element")[0]
tag = wrapping_element.xpath("x:tag", namespaces={"x": "url"})[0]

print(etree.tostring(tag, encoding="unicode"))
```

This will print...

```xml
<prefix:tag xmlns:prefix="url">value</prefix:tag>
```

Notice I used the prefix `x`. The prefix can match the prefix in the XML file, but it doesn't have to; only the namespace URIs need to match exactly.

See here for more details: http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes